# Base64 String to Image

Tags: php, rest, base64

I hava a rest-webservice and i want to upload the image as a base64 string and decode it on my webserver using php.

**My Code**:

```
if (isset($para['picture']) or isset($para['filetype']) )
        {
            if (isset($para['picture']) and isset($para['filetype']))
            {
                if (!($para['filetype'] == 'jpg' || $para['filetype'] == 'png'))
                {
                    $arr['Code'] = 617;
                    $arr['Message'] = $msg->getMessage(617);
                    $response->body = json_encode($arr);
                    return $response;
                }
                echo $para['picture'];
                $bin = base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', $para['picture']));

                if (strlen($bin) >(524288*2))
                {
                    $arr['Code'] = 624;
                    $arr['Message'] = $msg->getMessage(624);
                    $response->body = json_encode($arr);
                    return $response;
                }

                $uid = $dbmodel->getUid($sid);

                if($uid<1)
                {
                    $arr['Code'] = 699;
                    $arr['Message'] = $msg->getMessage(699);
                    $response->body = json_encode($arr);
                    return $response;

                }

                $file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/img/".$uid.".".$para['filetype'], 'w');
                fwrite($file, $bin);
                fclose($file);
                $dbmodel->insertPicture($uid,URL_ROOT."/img/".$uid.".".$para['filetype']);
            }
            else
            {
                $arr['Code'] = 616;
                $arr['Message'] = $msg->getMessage(616);
                $response->body = json_encode($arr);
                return $response;
            }
```

**DBModel**:

```
function insertPicture($uid,$link)
    {   
        $result = mysql_query("select link from USER_PICTURE where USER_ID=$uid");

        if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $row['link'];
            $split = explode("/img/",  $row['link']);
            unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/img/".$split[1]);
        }

        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO USER_PICTURE (user_id,link) VALUES ($uid, '$link')ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE link='$link'");

        if ($result)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I **call** my webservice with:

```
sid=3rcsg42ekbiats33uf2jto6u16&picture=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&filetype=jpg
```

I use the notepadd++ with mimetype plugin to convert a image to base64

**UPDATE:**

Picture Paramter in PHP:

```
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
```

**Problem**:

The DB Link will be set right, but the image doesn't appear in the webroot.

Please help

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the `img` folder?

Comment: yeah the permission of the img folder is set right, i can see the images placed there in my browser, and that code worked a few weeks ago sometimes

Comment: if you can see them: can you open them as an image? are the files corrupted?

Comment: the images are viewable; Now when i send a picture no new file appears in /img

Answer (score 0):

There is a "%3D" at the end of your base64 string. But there is no "%" in the base64 alphabet.

If this makes it into your image files, they might be invalid.

Regards

Stefan

Comment: No there is "irvk Sx4A64BVPyzRkgD2WSI0DCD anCKcssi" in there. but white spaces are not allowed either.

Comment: ok sorry the echo $var was without str_replace(' ', '+', $para['picture']); i updated the picture paramter